# ¿A que se debe el error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Intente instalar una libreria, y obtuve el siguiente error, aun cumpliendo los requisitos *creo*

[image: Error obtenido:]

Comment: La librería que estás intentando instalar tiene partes escritas en C y necesita que tengas instalado un compilador adecuado. No sé qué librería es, ni cómo has instalado Python en tu sistema, pero te recomendaría que usaras la distribución Anaconda, que trae su propio gestor (`conda install`) para instalar librerías adicionales en Windows que no requieren compilar las partes en C porque Anaconda ya las trae pre-compiladas para esa plataforma. Quizás la librería que necesitas no esté en conda, pero si está, esta vía será mucho más sencilla.

Comment: Python lo instale con el propio instalador. Como se hace para instalar el compilador que decis?

Comment: Hola Fernando: https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/. aunque creo que pydnp3 (que creo que intentas instalar) no es precisamente un paquete incluido.... Ten en cuenta que según la [documentación de Pydnp3](https://pypi.org/project/pydnp3/): "Supported Platforms: Linux, MacOS"...

Comment: Es decir, no puedes usar pip en teoría para instalar el paquete en windows, aún teniendo instalado el compilador y accesible para cmake. En principio debes compilar el paquete por ti mismo desde las fuentes usando cmake y teniendo un compilador para C++ 14

Answer (score 0):

Lo más adecuado es que instales python con la distribución de anaconda, descargándola [aquí](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Una vez tengas Anaconda instalado, puedes instalar el paquete con:

```
conda install -c anaconda cmake
```

También deberías instalarte PIP que es un instalador de paquetes para python ([guia instalar pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)), y si no te ha funcionado anaconda, realizar:

```
pip install cmake
```